# После перезахода в сцену кнопка share не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

Суть пробелмы такова - есть 2 сцены, сцена меню и сцена действий, запускаю приложение - кнопка share в сцене меню работает, перехожу в сцену действий `там тоже есть кнопка share` здесь работает в любых случаях, перехожу обратно в сцену меню и вот в этом случае уже не работает, не выдаёт никаких ошибок, для share использую [этот](https://github.com/ChrisMaire/unity-native-sharing) плагин.

> Пожалуйста обратите внимание на то что во второй сцене скрипт работает
>   как надо

После перезахода в главное меню и при нажатий на `share` то показывает только первый дебаг, соотвецтвенно не заходит дальше в методы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста код, в котором воспроизводится ваша проблема, или скриншоты, или вывод в консоль, что-нибудь, что поможет конкретизировать проблему. В данном виде, невозможно ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Второй дебаг выше тоже не виден, предполагаю что не загружаются файлы с DllImport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым!
При выходе из второй сцены включалась "Пауза", и при переходе в главное меню пауза оставалась.

Одно не пойму, раз остальные скрипты работали, так как я мог переходить в другие сцены, то почему этот не работал?